# CVGRIDSEARCH IN ML

Tags: python, linear-regression, logistic-regression, grid-search, gridsearchcv

while trying to carry out ML prediction on COVID-19 data ran to tthe problem. Any help
The code used
# define models and parameters
model = LogisticRegression()
solvers = ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear']
penalty = ['l2']
c_values = [100, 10, 1.0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001]

```
# define grid search
grid = dict(solver=solvers, penalty=penalty, C=c_values)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
grid_search =  GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, 
                       scoring='accuracy',error_score=0, iid=True)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# summarize results
print(f"Best: {grid_result.best_score_:.3f} using {grid_result.best_params_}")


TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iid'


# define models and parameters
model = LogisticRegression()
solvers = ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear']
penalty = ['l2']
c_values = [100, 10, 1.0, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001]

# define grid search
grid = dict(solver=solvers, penalty=penalty, C=c_values)
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=1)
grid_search =  GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=grid, n_jobs=-1, cv=cv, 
                       scoring='accuracy',error_score=0, iid=True)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

# summarize results
print(f"Best: {grid_result.best_score_:.3f} using {grid_result.best_params_}")
```

The error output
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iid'

Answer (score 1):

try removing 'iid=True' from all places

Comment: There is no ''iid=True anywhere

Comment: @Ayorinde Then what is this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqwN5.png